# Update database with dataviewgrid on joined query

Tags: sql, vb.net

Update my SQL Server with info provided by dataviewgrid changes, mainly a checkbox / bit field.

I can populate my dataviewgrid and I can even make it update if i only use a single table, the problem is I want my query to have three tables joined, just to display information.

I've tried to replicate some tutorials and make changes of my own but it just doesn't seems to click.

It has been a while since I've coded in VB so there's also that.

What I have so far:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim myDA1 As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet1 As DataSet
    Dim myDA2 As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet2 As DataSet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con2 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=CONNECTION STRING WORKS FINE")
        Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT x1,y2,z1 from a inner join b where a.x1=b.x2", con2)

        con2.Open()

        myDA2 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd2)
        Dim builder2 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(myDA2)

        myDataSet2 = New DataSet()
        myDA2.Fill(myDataSet2, "MyTable2")

        DataGridView2.DataSource = myDataSet2.Tables("MyTable2").DefaultView
        con2.Close()
        con2 = Nothing    
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView2_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellContentClick
        Me.Validate()
        Me.myDA2.Update(Me.myDataSet2.Tables("MyTable2"))
        Me.myDataSet2.AcceptChanges()
    End Sub 
End Class
```

It's updating on a basic query, yes, but i need to make it update on a join query.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, are you saying when you add joins to your query that displays the datagridview that the info no longer shows up? Also, are you sure it's actually updating the SQL Table or is it just updating your dataset? Unless I'm mistaken I don't see where you are updating the actual SQL Table, looks like you are only updating the dataset.

Comment: Write your query in SQL first then try to apply it to your VB code. You can perform an UPDATE on a query with a JOIN in it. However, once your data is in a new DataSet *it is no longer the original two (or more) sets of data*. Treat the new set as something different--because it is. SQL won't be able to parse through your VB datatable or dataset to "undo" the join. Which means you'll probably need to understand your table structure and update it based on the key values... so if you want assistance, it would help if you include the table structure in your post.

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "querry" - one "r" is **QUITE** enough !

Comment: From MS docs "If your DataTable maps to or is generated from a single database table, you can take advantage of the DbCommandBuilder object to automatically generate the DeleteCommand, InsertCommand, and UpdateCommand of the DbDataAdapter." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/generating-commands-with-commandbuilders  The important item is "single database table"

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment you cannot use a `CommandBuilder` when you use a join. You need to supply your own Update, Insert, and Delete commands for the DataAdapter. Be sure to use the overload of the Parameters.Add method that includes the name of the source column. This provides the mapping for the DataAdapter. I used a database on my machine to show the code. You would probably want to add commands for Insert and Delete.

```
Private da As SqlDataAdapter

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    da = New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim query = "Select Article.ArticleID, Article.Title, Author.LastName From Article Inner Join Author on Article.AuthorID = Author.AuthorID"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.PublishersConnection)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cn)
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim Uquery = "Update Article Set Title = @Title Where ArticleID = @ID;"
    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.PublishersConnection)
        Using UCommand As New SqlCommand(Uquery, cn)
            UCommand.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Title")
            UCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ArticleID")
            da.UpdateCommand = UCommand
            da.Update(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```